# Loop through, open, perform SendKeys on pdf files in one folder

Tags: vba, loops, pdf, sendkeys

```
Sub Password()
    'Loop through all files in a folder
Dim fileName As Variant
fileName = Dir("C:\State_K-1_Info\Password\*.pdf")

Do While fileName <> ""

    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open ("C:\State_K-1_Info\Password\001.pdf")
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00005
    'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
    'This example will print the file name to the immediate window
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys "^(s)", True
    Application.SendKeys "%{F4}", True

    'Set the fileName to the next file
    fileName = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Unfortunately this just continually opens and closes the first file in the folder which is referenced in my create object line

Comment: Because that's exactly what you're telling it to do. Didn't you mean to `.Open(fileName)` instead?

Comment: ^ Well probably the `fileName` and the path too.

Comment: When I do that, no files open.

Comment: @rbrb19 I made a mistake. As BigBen said, it should be `.Open("C:\etc\etc\" & fileName)`.