# Application.Wait Now causes my vba script not to loop through Dir

Tags: vba, loops, directory, wait

When I run this code without the `Application.Wait Now` it loops through all the files in the referenced folder. When I insert and `Application.Wait Now` command, it opens the first file, performs the send keys, saves and closes it, and continues to show that it is running but no document opens and nothing happens until I break the code. How can I resolve this?

I need the wait now commands to keep the sendkeys from running out of order.

```
Sub Password()
    'Loop through all files in a folder
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long
Dim Password As String
Dim fileName As Variant
With Sheet1
LastRow = .Range("C9999").End(xlUp).Row
fileName = Dir("C:\State_K-1_Info\Password\*.pdf")


Do While fileName <> ""

    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open ("C:\State_K-1_Info\Password\" & fileName)
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00005

    For CustRow = 2 To LastRow
     Password = .Range("C" & CustRow).Value

   Application.SendKeys "{F6}", True
     Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
     Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Application.SendKeys "^(s)", True
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
    Application.SendKeys "%{F4}", True
    Application.Wait Now + 0.00001


    Next CustRow
fileName = Dir
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: the keys will be happening in excel I believe

Comment: You probably actually don't need SendKeys at all. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60046336/loop-through-open-perform-sendkeys-on-pdf-files-in-one-folder

Comment: The SendKeys work within the pdf. I am using them to put a password on multiple pdf files (not all send keys included because they are not relevant to the issue). The problem is the Application.Wait Now, Is there some other method I can use to avoid the sendkeys getting ahead of themselves